# Click through a png overlayed on top of a Flash player

Tags: jquery, flash, jwplayer

Does anyone please have a solution to create a Clickthrough with jQuery on a png file overlayed on top of a Flash (JW) movie player?

Answer (score 0):

1) Put your flash movie in a DIV wrapper with `position:relative`.

2) Set your flash movie to have a parameter `wmode="opaque"`

3) Put your overlay DIV inside the wrapper with the same width and height of your movie, but give it a `z-index` value, `position:absolute;top:0;left:0`

4) Hook up the client event for the overlay